# multivariate normal vector in spherical coordinates

Tags: statistics

Let $X \sim N_p(0, I)$ be random vector of dimension $p$ with standard normal distribution.To define $X$ in spherical coordinates we need to define direction "$\varphi$" and length "$r$" of vector $X$. Show that:
1) $\varphi$ and $r$ are independent 
2) $\varphi$ is evenly distributed on unit sphere
3) $r^2$ is distributed as chi-square with $p$ degrees of freedom.

Comment: Could you show your workings for what you're tried so far? This reads a lot like you're asking us to do your homework without you trying. If you're stuck on something say where and what the issue is.

Comment: I can write what i have done so far but i don't know yet how to edit formulas on this site so it would look ugly. I know actually that it is very simple problem (i am too stupid) and i thought that for someone it would take just few minutes

Comment: I have solved this problem, can we delete this?